# How to prepare number of bind variables to match the number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

Firstly, I know that this is a repeating question and I'm asking the same question. But I have read all the solution provided that linked to the same problem, but when I followed the suggested solution, it will trigger more warnings to appear. 
This is what I have in my code

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM emergency WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a, NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
```

to get the

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
>   match number of fields in prepared statement in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gsd\emergency\records.php on line 122

so I change the codes into

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT date, patient_seen_u, patient_seen_a FROM emergency WHERE id ='?'"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a ,NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
}
```

only to get these warning;

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gsd\emergency\records.php on line 119
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
>   match number of fields in prepared statement in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gsd\emergency\records.php on line 122

and also try to do this;

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `date`, `patient_seen_u`,`patient_seen_a`  FROM `emergency` WHERE `id` = '?'"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a ,NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
}
```

but the code is not working either. How can I solve this?

Comment: So What is $id?

Comment: it use to get the id from the URL  $id = $_GET['id'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes surrounding the placeholder and also add the id column to match the arrangement order for `bind_result`

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, date, patient_seen_u, patient_seen_a FROM emergency WHERE id =?")) {

$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);// bind as integer 


$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, date, patient_seen_u, patient_seen_a FROM emergency WHERE id =?")) 
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($date, $patient_seen_u, $patient_seen_a ,NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
}
```

and now it's working fine. Thank you.